Does this theorem for groups generalize to positive integers greater than 2?
I know that if a group $G$ satisfies the equation $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$, it is automatically a commutative group. I want to know if this relation generalizes to positive integer exponents greater than $2$. For example, if $G$ satisfies the equation $(xy)^3=x^3y^3$, is it commutative? In fact, I would be very interested if there exists a group $G$ which satisfies the infinitely many equations $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ for all positive integers $n$ greater than or equal to $3$, but is not commutative. Is there even such a group? But, first I want to know if there exists a group $G$ and a positive integer $n$ greater than or equal to $3$ which satisfies $(xy)^n=x^ny^n$ but is not commutative. Also, I want to know what the least such $n$ is. Is it $3$?

There is a group of order $27$ with $x^3=1$ for all $x \in G$ and in fact for all $n \ge 3$ there are non-commutative groups with $x^n=1$ for all $x \in  G$. See also this post
